# December CU SP 2010

Tags: service-application

My question is during  December CU installation period(In sharepoint servers)..any outage???(i agree while  running psconfig after the installation, there will be outage...but during December CU package installation is there any outage for sharepoint sites ?)

fyi: In my environment is 2 app server , 2 wfe and 1 cluster db

Please suggest us

Comment: Hi @Mohan, if you ask a question and find an answer to your question, you should mark it as the answer.  This will encourage others to help you in future and let others know which answer was in fact the answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks..How will make it as answer ? where i have to click ?

Comment: Under the number of votes for the answer there is a tick, click it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there will be an outage. The CU package, just like every other, needs to be installed on all web frontends. You will need to bring your farm offline whilst you do this.

I would do it over a weekend to give you time to troubleshoot any issues that may come up.

However, always *always* **ALWAYS** test the CU on a copy of your live environment, to anticipate any issues that might come up or that might otherwise interfere with the working of your environment, or any customisations you have applied.

And, needless to say, take a backup of all your content databases before doing the update.

Comment: Just re-emphasising *always* :D

Comment: How will make it as answer ? where i have to click ?

Comment: As you mentioned Only  All WFE Servers..What about application Servers..i guess we have to install all the sharepoint servers(both WFE and App Server)Right???

Comment: Yep you need to install it on all servers where sharepoint is installed

Comment: To mark as answer, click the tick below the 'down arrow' next to the answer most appropriate.